# Re-run Jest when jest.config changes

Tags: jestjs

I am working with a jests.config.js file:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
    setupFiles: ["./helpers/setup/environment.js"],
    testMatch: ["**/__tests__/v2/tests.cloud.js"],
    globals: {
        _: true,
    },
    watchPathIgnorePatterns: ["./src/dataset", "./logs"],
};
```

I run Jest with watch:

```
jest --watch
```

In order to develop each test on its own I change the test file on **testMatch** every time I move on to the next test I am writing. Is there a way for the watch to reload the Jest config itself when the configuration file changes?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty other options

### CLI [TestPathPattern]

if you run `jest --help` you'll see you can pass TestPathPattern to match test files

```sh
$ jest --help
Usage: jest.js [--config=<pathToConfigFile>] [TestPathPattern]
```

---

### --onlyChanged, -o

Jest will attempt to run only tests related to the changed (in the current repository) files.

---

### watch mode (p)

While in `--watch` mode you can press `P` and enter regex to select which file to run

Comment: @Guy my answer doesn't really answers your question, but `testMatch` isn't really intended to be changed with each test

Comment: Yes, I realise it is not the intended use, but as I write one test at a time, it is easier for me to change it every 10 minutes or so when I move on to the next suite and work with "npm test" rather than going through the cli history

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a short NodeJS script:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const filename = "../jest.config.js";

let jest;

const run = () => {
    if (jest) {
        jest.kill();
    }

    jest = spawn("jest", ["--watch"], { stdio: "inherit" });
};

run();
fs.watch(filename, run);

process.on("SIGINT", function() {
    console.log("Caught interrupt signal");
    process.exit();
});
```